# passing variables between jst.haml and .html.hamlc files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm pretty new to RoR and right now I'm trying to figure out how to pass variables from `.jst.hamlc` to `.html.hamlc`.

I have something like this in a `.jst.hamlc` file

```
- @myvar = 'myvalue'
```

and I need to manipulate `@myvar` in the `.html.hamlc` file but it looks like `@myvar` is always blank.

Any help or clue will be awesome!